# Formatting bug with strikeout

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown, firefox

I tried strike out several paragraphs of text by using a single pair of `<s>`  `</s>` tags wrapping all of the text; but only the first and last paragraphs were struck out.

Example 1:

<s>First paragraph.  Should be struck out.</s>

Second paragraph.  Should be struck out.

Third paragraph.  Should be struck out.

Fourth paragraph.  Should be struck out.

I also discovered if there's a blank line between the tags and the text that nothing is struck at all.

Example 2:

First paragraph.  Should be struck out.  This time an empty line is between the  <s> and this paragraph.

Second paragraph.  Should be struck out.

Third paragraph.  Should be struck out.

Fourth paragraph.  Should be struck out.  This time an empty line is between the  </s> and this paragraph.

**Screenshot taken in FF7**
[image: http://orthogonaltonormal.com/midden/FF7.png]

Comment: I don't see the issue. Please post a link that shows the issue.

Comment: @Oded looks like it's browser specific.  It's happening in FF7, but not IE8 or Chrome 15.

Comment: @DanNeely A screenshot would be helpful in this case.

Comment: @AnnaLear  I'll upload one in ~2 hours when I'm home from work.

Comment: No-repro. All paragraphs struck. WebKit browser on MacOS.

Comment: Worked in Opera too.  Unless it affects FF 3.6 (only old FF version with significant user share); this can probably be filed under not worth fixing.

Comment: Maybe some Firefox plugin you have messing with the HTML layout?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The only plugin I have that should be messing with the page would be ABP; disabling it was the first thing I tried.  It didn't help.

Comment: Hmm.. as it happens only with FF7 so far think it's indeed not worth spending much time on it then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. In HTML, [`<s>` is an inline element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-S), meaning that it is not intended to contain multiple paragraphs or other “block” content; if you do, it is up to browser error-recovery what results. You should strike out each paragraph individually, or use `<del>` instead, which can be used as either block or inline.

Comment: and it's one, two, three strikes "You're Out" in the ...

Comment: … old HTML game.

Comment: ... or you should use DEL, since it can act as a block-level element *or* an inline-level one, quite uniquely (apart from its sister element, INS) for HTML. And, unlike STRIKE/S, it's not deprecated ...

Answer (score -1):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

With broswer version (from `about:`):

```
Google Chrome   17.0.963.12 (Official Build 114667) dev-m
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.11 (@102901)
JavaScript  V8 3.7.12.6
Flash   11,1,102,55
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.12 Safari/535.11
Command Line    "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```